# I want a conditional expression to use in Expression Transformer of Informatica

Tags: informatica

IF LUP=NULL then COD, if not then check if LUP<=COD, if COD is greater than equal to LUP, then COD else LUP?

I want the above statement to be converted into an expression so that, I can use this in Expression Transformer of Informatica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this -
`IIF (ISNULL(LUP), COD, IIF(LUP<=COD,COD ,LUP))`